# Не отображается SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW Android 10

Tags: java, android

На `Android 10` а именно на девайсе *Samsung s10* (возможно дело в его специфике?) не отображается алерт по верх других приложений.

**Пермишены:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

**Получаю пермишен:**

```
private boolean checkOverlayPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName())), OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Добавляю окно так:**

```
private void initOverlay() {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(displayMetrics.widthPixels
                , displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        layoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
        layoutParams.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            layoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        } else {
            layoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
        }
        windowManager.addView(view, layoutParams);
    }
```

В дереве `View` контейнер - `FrameLayout`